# Bootstrap typeahead is not displaying AJAX results

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-typeahead

Before asking I want to say that this is not a duplicated topic. I've already tried with:

- [Pwarelis](https://github.com/pwarelis/Ajax-Typeahead)' fork
- [Tcrosen's](https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead) one
- [Gudbergur's](https://gist.github.com/1866577) code

...and many others, and I also read lots of *Q&A*, but none of them is what I am looking for.
All what I tried works with predefinite string sources, but when I do the next step: AJAX remote source, it is just showing no results on the dropdown list.

**UPDATE - My code** *(don't understand why negative votes. Well written, well strucuted ;))*

*The html file*

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<input id="myElement" class="typeahead" type="text">

<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$('#myElement').typeahead({
ajax: '/php/ajax.php'
});
</script>
[...]
```

*The ajax.php file:*

```
<?php
echo "[{ id: 1, name: 'Terry'}, { id: 2, name: 'Mark'}, { id: 3, name: 'Jack'}]";
?>
```

It's not an AJAX issue, because it is working in other cases at the same machine.
What may I try to fix it?, I am really crashing up my head since a few days. Thanks for reading.

Comment: What is the output of the `urlencode(mySource)` from the AJAX result?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Hi, thanks for helping. Result is this:`%5B%7B+id%3A+1%2C+name%3A+%27Terry%27%7D%2C+%7B+id%3A+2%2C+name%3A+%27Mark%27%7D%2C+%7B+id%3A+3%2C+name%3A+%27Jacob%27%7D%5D`

Comment: My doubt was that, it might have some BOM characters. But it doesn't seem that way.

Comment: Can you show the full code of AJAX implementation?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I updated it with my own full code. (It uses tcrosen's fork)

Comment: Yeah, will check the original code too.

Comment: Dude, what you have done is right. Nothing is wrong in the implementation part. No idea why it is not working. :(

Comment: @PraveenKumar Will keep seeking for information!. Thanks anyway! ;)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Answered my self with a better alternative. Greetings!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People who vote negative **without even knowing the right answer** should think a bit before acting. If someone needs a real nice/working/magic autocomplete script, here wo go:

[Real good Autocomplete Script](http://www.brandspankingnew.net/specials/ajax_autosuggest/ajax_autosuggest_autocomplete.html)

**Description**: This adds a pulldown menu of suggested values to a text field. The user can either click directly on a suggestion to enter it into the field, or navigate the list using the up and down arrow keys, selecting a value using the enter key. The values for the suggestion list are to provided as XML, or as JSON *(by a PHP script, or similar)*.

*Thanks those who made negative points disappear ;)*

Answer (score 0):

hey set header of json in you php file 
use `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

for more info on header plese visit [here(stackoverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-content-type-http-header-for-json) ad for example [visit here(www.funnenjoy.com)](http://funnenjoy.com)